# Mnemonics for memorizing $\overline{g:F(A)\to B}=G(g)\circ \eta_A$ and $\overline {f:A\to G(B)}=\epsilon_B\circ F(f)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors, mnemonic

Let $F:\mathscr A\to \mathscr B$ be a left adjoint to $G:\mathscr B\to\mathscr A$. Write overline $(\overline {\circ})$ for the (either direction) of the bijection $$\mathscr B(F(A),B)\simeq \mathscr B(A,G(B))$$
It's known that $\overline{g:F(A)\to B}=G(g)\circ \eta_A$ and $\overline {f:A\to G(B)}=\epsilon_B\circ F(f)$, where $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ are the unit and counit of the adjunction.

These equalities are easy to prove (by applying the naturality in $A$ and $B$ to the arrows $g$ or $f$), but I'm having a hard time memorizing them (and proving them all the time I need them is not very practical). Is there an easy way to memorize these equalities?  Are there any mnemonics maybe?

Comment: I feel that there's not much to memorise. If you remember that $\eta_A$ is a morphism $A \to G F A$ then the most obvious way of getting a morphism $A \to G B$ from $g : F A \to B$ is to apply $G$ and precompose $\eta_A$.

Comment: To add to @ZhenLin's comment, I always start with the identity $I_{FA}$ to get to your $\eta_A$, and similarly for your $\epsilon_B$. BTW, I, for one, am not inclined to  sneer at a request for mnemonics. And a professional cat. theorist, Eugenia Cheng, in the fabulous youtube catster sequence, offers the fabulous explanation that the free functor must be the left adjoint, and not the right, as free and left have the same number of letters. A fabulous fact/proof to be cherished.

Comment: @peterag: About free/forgetful functors, I learnt this sentence: "To forget is right."

Comment: In case anyone is interested, Eugenia Cheng also mentions what @peterag said [in this talk](https://youtu.be/cSRVywjDP8E?t=4709) (around 1:18:40), and in the same talk she also mentions yet another way of remembering that free functors are left adjoints: "left-wing views are about freedom".